# php codecept.phar run (codeception)

Tags: php, html, curl, codeception

I have installed Codeception following the guide on their website. Create first test.

> $I = new WebGuy($scenario);
>
> $I->wantTo('ensure that frontpage works');
>
> $I->amOnPage('/');
>
> $I->see('Homepage');

And what we have when we start testing php codecept.phar run:

> Codeception PHP Testing Framework v1.6.5
>   Powered by PHPUnit 3.7.23 by Sebastian Bergmann.
>   PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER - assumed 'CURLOPT
>   _SSL_VERIFYPEER' in phar://C:/wamp/www/codecept.phar/src/Codeception/Configurati
>   on.php on line 163
>
> PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER - assumed 'CURLOPT
>   _SSL_VERIFYPEER' in phar://C:/wamp/www/codecept.phar/src/Codeception/Module/PhpB
>   rowser.php on line 80
>
> [Guzzle\Common\Exception\RuntimeException]
>   The PHP cURL extension must be installed to use Guzzle.
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER - assumed 'CURLOPT_SSL_
>   VERIFYPEER' in phar://C:/wamp/www/codecept.phar/src/Codeception/Configuration.ph
>   p on line 163
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER - assumed 'CURLOPT_SSL_
>   VERIFYPEER' in phar://C:/wamp/www/codecept.phar/src/Codeception/Module/PhpBrowse
>   r.php on line 80

Using WAMP on Windows 7 Ultimate. PHP ver 5.4.16. Apache ver 2.4.4. CURL is enabled in settings. I don't know what need to do to solved this problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please enable CURL extension in PHP.

Oh. It might be that you have 2 PHP configs: one for Apache (with CURL enabled) and second for CLI with CURL disabled. Please check that PHP you use in console actually have CURL enabled.

Comment: Thanks for help, solved the problem, one of them was disabled.